# Count with Group By always shows '1'

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the number of articles mentioning Donald Trump exist in a Google BigQuery table.

```
SELECT
  sourcecommonname,
  COUNT(DISTINCT sourcecommonname) counter
FROM
  `israel_media`
WHERE
  persons LIKE '%donald trump%'
GROUP BY
  sourcecommonname
```

Results are always

| sourcecommonname | counter |
| --- | --- |
| first_newspaper | 1 |
| second_newspaper | 1 |
| third_newspaper | 1 |
| forth_newspaper | 1 |

What am I not seeing?

Comment: use `COUNT(*) counter` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT sourcecommonname) counter`

Comment: You are counting distinct values grouped by these very values.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  You are counting *distinct* values.  But there is only one value per group.  That is what the `group by` does.

Perhaps you just want `count()` without `distinct`:

```
SELECT sourcecommonname,
       COUNT(*) as counter
FROM `israel_media`
WHERE persons LIKE '%donald trump%'
GROUP BY sourcecommonname
```